# Please, explain, what means when _ is passed to a function in js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'underscore',
'backbone',
'models/Evaluate'
], function ($, _, Backbone, Evaluate) {

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Evaluate,
    url:'evaluate/process'
});

return MyCollection;
});
```

or there are also cases, when _ is returned from a function

```
return _;
```

Comment: It's what underscore is known by when you pass it into the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` is a variable name. In this case, it is referring to the JavaScript library Underscore.

Comment: so when there is a _, than it is always an underscore?

Comment: @user2814599: The `_` doesn't always have to refer to the Underscore.js library.  `_` is just a variable name, it could refer to anything.  It's just in this case that it refers to the library.

Answer (score 0):

This is the name of the variable that holds the underscore plugin.

In a similar manner, the `$` character is used for jQuery.

**Both of these can be changed, but these are the defaults that each library sets up.**

---

In your example, you are using requireJS to load dependencies, these will be passed in the same order that they are listed. jQuery first and then underscore, this is why the function is passed:

```
function ($, _, ...)
     //   ---^ underscoreJS
     //   ^ jQuery
```

---

Hands on example:

Calling the `uniq` underscore function:

```
_.uniq([1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]);
```

Calling the `each` jQuery function:

```
$.each([ 52, 97 ], function(...) );
```

Answer (score 0):

`_` is the name of a variable. The same as `$` is a variable commonly used as an alias for `jQuery` variable.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript allows you to name your variables/functions with various characaters, such as: `$`, `_`

So given that, this probably another variable name.